# CSS Fail - background-position, background-repeat, background-size, background-attachment

Tags: css, background, background-position, background-size, background-repeat

When I put the following into a `div` in the main `body`, this WORKS:

```
<div style="display: block; width:100%; height: 100%; min-height: 100vh; background-color: #FFFFFF; background: url(./images/pic.jpg); background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-attachment: fixed;">
```

BUT when I use CSS is DOES NOT WORK:

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
.myMainDiv {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
</style>

<div class="myMainDiv" style="display: block; background: url(./images/pic.jpg);">
```

It seems to be going wrong, because I need a different pic for each background and then this results in the `background-repeat` etc being ignored. (Note: also different divs will have different display values, either block or none, so they need to be separately stated as well, but that is not the problem.)

Anyone know why and if there is a workaround.

Comment: did you include `.myMainDiv {...}` between `<style>` and `</style>`?

Comment: Are you putting it inside <style> tag?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I did. Updated to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm. Seems you are overwriting your CSS. Using `backgorund: url('./images/pic.jpg')` as an inline style is the problem. You are overwriting all of your CSS properties (`background-position`, `background-repeat`, etc...) with this inline style. Replace `backgorund: url('./images/pic.jpg')` with `backgorund-image: url('./images/pic.jpg')`.

Comment: Wow. Fast work. So fast in fact I will have to mark this as answer in 8 minutes time as it will not allow me to do so before then.